# Add Application Insights to an azure function with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-cli

I have a PowerShell script which creates an azure function app on a consumption plan and its associated storage account within a resource group using the azure cli following the example [In the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/scripts/functions-cli-create-serverless)

However to enable application insights I have to go to the azure portal, find the func select monitor and click enable application insights.

How can I expand that script to enable automate this step for the newly created function?  I have been unable to find any specific documentation or examples and   I would prefer to avoid resource templates if possible.

Comment: Is this about Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI?  The title and text are conflicting. :)

Comment: I'm using the azure cli from a powershell script

Comment: No Confusion @JoyWang I'm waiting to see if there is another answer which automates the inisights creation

Comment: AFAIK, azure cli does not support to create app insights directly, please refer to [command list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest),  if you want to access it, you could try [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-create).

Comment: So no way to automate creation of application insights other than resource templates in json?

Comment: Yes, the only possible way is creating it by resource I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OF course, you could enable Application Insights to the azure function by Azure CLI.

But you need to create the **Application Insights** in the portal first, currently, it is unable to create Application Insights via Azure CLI.

You could follow the steps below.

1.Go to your Application Insights in the portal, copy the `Instrumentation Key` in the screenshot.

[image]

2.After creating the function app by your command , just use the CLI command below.

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name <functionname> --resource-group <resourcegroupname> --settings 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = <Instrumentation Key>'
```

It works fine on my side, you could check it in the portal.

[image]

[image]